# What's Next Center of an Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, notation

Let $A$ be an algebra with a bilinear map $m: A \times A \to A$ (multiplication). So we define the center of $A$ as the commutative elements of $A$:

$$Z(A) = \{ a \in A \mid a.a' = a' . a, ~ \forall a' \in A \}$$
(The idea can be extended to another algebraic structures, like groups and rings.)

I want to know if there is a terminology/symbol/definition of the elements of $A$ that are associatives, or [flexibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_algebra), or [alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_algebra). Ex:

$$F(A) = \{ a \in A \mid a.(b.a) = (a.b).a, ~ \forall b \in A \}$$